# How to identify IP Ranges in AutoHotkey

Tags: if-statement, ip, autohotkey, range

The script that I am using has a variable named SourceIP.  I have some static lists of IP Ranges for VPN Pools.  How can I set up a searching logic to determine in which IP Pool the Source IP resides?

Here are the example details:

SourceIP = 15.15.7.49

VPNpool1 = 15.15.1.0 - 15.15.9.255

VPNPool2 = 15.15.10.0 - 15.15.19.255

Normally when I want to see if an value is in a list of values I use **If VARIABLE contains ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEMn**. This method won't work for VPN Pool ranges because I would have to list out **every** IP. I am hoping someone knows how I can make this work.

Perhaps something like:

```
If SourceIP in VPNPool1 

{

MsgBox The SourceIP is from VPNPool1

}

If SourceIP in VPNPool12

{

MsgBox The SourceIP is from VPNPool2

}

Else 

{

MsgBox The SourceIP is not in a VPNPool.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Make sure you have the latest AutoHotkey version which supports objects.

```
IP := "15.15.9.254"
Start := "15.15.1.0" 
End := "15.15.9.255"
if InIPRange(IP, Start, End)
    msgbox yes
else
    msgbox no

InIPRange(strIP, strStart, strEnd) {

    arrIPRanges := {}
    loop, parse, strStart, .
        arrIPRanges[A_Index, A_LoopField] := A_LoopField        
    loop, parse, strEnd, .
        arrIPRanges[A_Index, A_LoopField] := A_LoopField
    loop, parse, strIP, .
    {
        if arrIPRanges[A_Index].MinIndex() > A_LoopField
            return false
        if arrIPRanges[A_Index].MaxIndex() < A_LoopField
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to vote you up, but this seems to work.  Now I get to figure out how.  Thanks for the direction.

Comment: @user1854504 To vote, you may need more reputation points. You can earn some points by marking a question as solved.